# Show GDB console in NetBeans

Tags: netbeans, gdb

Is there a way to show the GDB console so I can enter commands directly when debugging in NetBeans?

I am debugging a project and there are some GTK functions in the Call Stack that go to disassembly. I have the source files downloaded, but I need to input the `dir` command so GDB knows where to look for them.

Answer (score 3):

I finally found, it was at Window -> Debugging -> Debugger Console.